# use GroupedListView in StreamBuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have docs in my collection, there are 2 fields. (String notes, Int date),
Date type is int because it sent like this : `DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch`

I want to group items using time, Like the below picture

[image]

---

Before this, I used ListView.Builder to list the items. It worked without problem.(Below code)

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: _FirebaseDB,
      builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text(
                      snapshot.data.docs[index]["note"],
                    );
                  },
                ),
            : Container();
      }),
    );
```

I wanted to group items. So I used, `grouped_list: ^5.1.2` package and changed code like this,

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: _FirebaseDB,
      builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                child: GroupedListView(
                  elements: [snapshot.data.docs],
                  groupBy: snapshot.data.docs["time"],
                  groupHeaderBuilder: (element) => Text("Group"),
                  itemBuilder: (context, element) {
                    return Card(
                      elevation: 8,
                      child: Text(snapshot.data.docs["note"]),
                    );
                  },
                )
                )
            : Container();
      }),
    );
```

Its not working. It showing error like this :

**type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'**

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,
dynamic>>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, 
dynamic>>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#63cd8):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this,

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: _FirebaseDB,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (!streamSnapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
          return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
            elements: streamSnapshot.data!.docs,
            groupBy: (element) =>
            element['time'],
            groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                value,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style:
                    const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
            floatingHeader: true,
            order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
            itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) {
              return Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(element['note']),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
```